# Clean user HTML in .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html, sanitization

My C# site allows users to submit HTML to be displayed on the site. I would like to limit the tags and attributes allowed for the HTML, but am unable to figure out how to do this in .net.

I've tried using [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack), but I don't see how to modify the HTML, I can see how to go through the HTML and find certain data, but actually generating an output file is baffling me.

Does anyone have a good example for cleaning up HTML in .net? The agility pack might be the answer, but the documentation is lacking.

Comment: Good question. This is at the top of my list whenever I allow HTML code to be submitted and displayed - generally I use controls that format and sanitize the result for me (i.e. www.freetextbox.com in ASP.NET) but I should really confirm the result too. +1 for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With HtmlAgilityPack you can remove unwanted tags from the input:

```
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```

Comment: That's the method I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommend [Microsoft's Anti-XSS Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/securitytools/archive/2009/09/17/anti-xss-library-v3-1-released.aspx) for santizing input.  It supports sanitizing html.

Answer (score 3):

You should only accept well-formed HTML.

You can then use LINQ to XML to parse and modify it.

You can make a recursive function that takes an element from the user and returns a new element with a whitelisted set of tags and attributes.

For example:

```
//Maps allowed tags to allowed attributes for the tags.
static readonly Dictionary<string, string[]> AllowedTags = new Dictionary<string, string[]>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    { "b",    new string[0] },
    { "img",  new string[] { "src", "alt" } },
    //...
};
static XElement CleanElement(XElement dirtyElement) {
    return new XElement(dirtyElem.Name,
        dirtyElement.Elements
            .Where(e => AllowedTags.ContainsKey(e.Name))
            .Select<XElement, XElement>(CleanElement)
            .Concat(
                dirtyElement.Attributes
                    .Where(a => AllowedTags[dirtyElem.Name].Contains(a.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            );
}
```

If you allow hyperlinks, make sure to disallow `javascript:` urls; this code doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

A tool you can use that is available off of SourceForge is [SGMLReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader) which turns the HTML into properly formatted XML and allows you to read it as an XmlReader or load it into an XmlDocument object for further processing.  I have used this before for parsing web pages which are not always in properly formatted HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) which is Open Source and created by the guys here?

Answer (score 0):

Jeff Atwood posted his whitelist-based approach on Refactor My Code at http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html

I believe StackOverflow combines that with the tag-balancing code at http://refactormycode.com/codes/360-balance-html-tags for sanitizing posts and preparing them for display. And, of course, they use MarkdownSharp for enabling Markdown on posts.